# Disable Input, Select properties when div is hidden dynamically

Tags: jquery

i have dynamic input field and div with calulcations, there are 4 div getting controlled using show and hide method and dropdown selection of number of visitors.

my problem is, i want to disable all the input, select , radio elements in these 4 div until it is getting shown, it should be disabled by default. and when we select no of visitor 2, it will show the person2 div and all input, select should be working in this div and if it is getting hidden again, the elements should be disabled.

here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('change', '#visitorcount', function() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (i <= $('#visitorcount').val()) {
        $('#person' + i).show();
        if ($('#country' + i).is(":hidden")) {
          $('#country' + i).val($('#country1').val());
        }
        $('#country' + i).show();
        //$("input, select, radio").prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $('#person' + i).hide();
        $('#country' + i).hide();
        //$("input, select, radio").prop('disabled', true);
      }
    }
  });
  $('body').on('change', '.ct,#visitorcount', function() {
    var priceforcountry = 0;
    $('.ct').each(function(index, element) {
      if ($(element).parent().is(":visible")) {
        priceforcountry += +$('option:selected', this).data('fee');
        //console.log($(element).parent().html());
      }
    });
    $('#totalcost').text(priceforcountry);
    //alert(priceforcountry);
  });


  $('.ct').trigger('change'); //ADD HERE
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="person1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">Citizenship</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select class="form-control ct" id="country1" name="maincountry">

        <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
        <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="totalcost">

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 control-label" data-xtr-key="Count of visitors">Number of Visitors</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select name="visitorcount" class="form-control" id="visitorcount">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row visitor" id="person2" style="display:none">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">Citizenship</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select class="form-control ct" id="country2" name="maincountry">

        <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
        <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row visitor" id="person3" style="display:none">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">Citizenship</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select class="form-control ct" id="country3" name="maincountry">

        <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
        <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row visitor" id="person4" style="display:none">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">Citizenship</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select class="form-control ct" id="country4" name="maincountry">

        <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
        <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row visitor" id="person5" style="display:none">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">Citizenship</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select class="form-control ct" id="country5" name="maincountry">

        <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
        <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem is now its getting disabled all over the form, not only to the divs where we want.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5xy4ba8g/1/ ?

Comment: @DavidThomas : yes .i want the same functionality but how to use it in my existing code, because i need to control of the prices and all calulcations.

Comment: "*how to use it in my existing code,*" - in what way does it not work with your existing code?

Comment: if i use your code along with mine, it simply don't  work, like the control of showing and hiding divs and all.  did you checked it with my fiddle?

Comment: No, I didn't. But since your Stack Snippet didn't work, and was a bit of a mess, I felt it was easier to start over rather than try and fit in with the rest of what you're doing. Incidentally, what is the rest of the code supposed to be doing that this code has to work alongside?

Comment: @DavidThomas: Look at my fiddle now, now it must be working, i just commented out two lines, that was causing the issue. you will understand it.

Comment: Well you are selecting all of the elements on the page, not the one in the div you are hiding and showing

Comment: @epascarello : can you help me with this? i just not able to solve it.

Comment: um something like..... `$(element).find('input')`

Answer (score 0):

i made it work by this updated code

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').on('change', '#visitorcount', function() {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                if (i <= $('#visitorcount').val()) {
                    $('#person' + i).show();
                    if ($('#country' + i).is(":hidden")) {
                        $('#country' + i).val($('#country1').val());
                    }
                    $('#country' + i).show();
                    //$("input, select, radio").prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#person' + i).find('input, textarea, button, select').prop('disabled', false);

                } else {
                    $('#person' + i).hide();
                    $('#country' + i).hide();
                    //$("input, select, radio").prop('disabled', true); 
                    $('#person' + i).find('input, textarea, button, select').prop('disabled', true);
                }
            }
        });
        $('body').on('change', '.ct,#visitorcount', function() {
            var priceforcountry = 0;
            $('.ct').each(function(index, element) {
                if ($(element).parent().is(":visible")) {
                    priceforcountry += +$('option:selected', this).data('fee');
                    // console.log($(element).parent().html());
                }
            });
            $('#totalcost').text(priceforcountry);

        });


        $('.ct').trigger('change');
        $('#visitorcount').trigger('change');

    });


</script>
```